# How to traverse a matrix starting from a random position in Java

Tags: java, matrix, traversal

I'm trying to write a simple Java program that can traverse a matrix (2D-Array) starting from any position in the matrix that the user specifies.
I started by declaring my matrix and filling it with random numbers, but I'm not sure where to go from here? How can I be able to traverse every cell in my matrix starting from a random position?

I'm just looking to have something basic and not very advanced because I'm still a beginner in Java, any help would be much appreciated!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
               
    // Initialize Matrix randomly
    int R = 3;
    int C = 3;
        
    int[][] matrix = new int[R][C];
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
    
            matrix[i][j] = ((int) (Math.random() * 2));
    
        }
    }
    
    //---------------------------
        
    // Robot Moving Algorithm
    
    int i, j, rows=R, cols=C, m, n;
    int Robot_i=0, Robot_j=0;
        
    if (Robot_i==0) {
        
        for (i=Robot_i; i<rows; i++) {
                
                
                
        }
    }

}
```

Here's an overview of what I'm looking for:

```
8 5 1
7 3 2
6 9 4
```

expected output, starting from row 0, col 1: `5,1,2,4,9,6,7,8,3`

Comment: Please make sure to always intent you code. This is a mess to read and it will confuse you more than you want.

Comment: How would you solve this in your brain? Where do you go from the starting position? Is your goal not to visit a field twice if possible? Then you need a data structure to remember which ones you've always visited.

Comment: Do you mean, from starting cell you want to go to the end (left to right and top to bottom) and then loop to the first cell and keep going until the starting cell? Can you provide an example with a 3x3 or 4x4 matrix and the expected output?

Comment: @Bentaye Yes, that's exactly what I'm looking to do! here's an overview of what I'm looking for: https://paste.pics/GLAUW

I want to know how to make the movement (left to right/top to bottom) but I have no idea where to begin.
and here's how I'm imagining the movement: https://paste.pics/GLAVW

Comment: @HackrMan is the way you traverse (in a spiral motion) a strong requirement, or would it be ok to have 5,1,7,3,2,6,9,4,8 (line by line) ?

Comment: @Bentaye, spiral traversal is not a requirement, I'm looking for anything that would allow me to traverse the matrix starting from any position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say we have this matrix:

```
[9, 5, 9]
[1, 0, 3]
[1, 2, 0]
```

you can also think of it as an array
`[9, 5, 9, 1, 0, 3, 1, 2, 0]`

and you can map any coordinates in the matrix to its corresponding index in the array, ex:
the `2` at coordinates row 2, col 1 has index 7

here are 2 methods to map coords to index and vice versa

```
private static int toIndex(int row, int col, int nbCols) {
    return col + row * nbCols;
}

private static int[] toCoords(int index, int nbCols) {
    return new int[] { index / nbCols, index % nbCols };
}
```

And here is a utility method to print your matrix

```
private static void printMatrix(int[][] matrix) {
    for (int[] ints : matrix) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ints));
    }
}
```

Now with these tools:

- Calculate the start index of the robot
- Iterate in the array to the end (the array has size nbRows * nbCols).
- Start again iterating from index 0 to the start index of the robot.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Initialize Matrix randomly
    int nbRows = 3;
    int nbCols = 3;

    int[][] matrix = new int[nbRows][nbCols];

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = ((int) (Math.random() * 10));
        }
    }

    printMatrix(matrix);

    //---------------------------

    // Robot Moving Algorithm

    int robotRow = 0;
    int robotCol = 1;

    int robotStartIndex = toIndex(robotRow, robotCol, nbCols);

    for (int i = robotStartIndex; i < nbCols * nbCols; i++) {
        int[] coords = toCoords(i, nbCols);
        System.out.println(matrix[coords[0]][coords[1]]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < robotStartIndex; i++) {
        int[] coords = toCoords(i, nbCols);
        System.out.println(matrix[coords[0]][coords[1]]);
    }

}
```

prints out:

```
[9, 5, 9]
[1, 0, 3]
[1, 2, 0]
5
9
1
0
3
1
2
0
9
```

Comment: This is Brilliant, Thank you so much!
There's only one thing that I pointed out in my explanation sketch but didn't mention in the comments, which was the fact that I want the robot to be able to move one cell at a time, for instance, if the robot is in the position [0][2] it can only move down to [1][2] or left to [0][1].
I'll try to figure this one and see if I can make it work.